# How does Windows 8 map the USB HID multitouch device to a specific display?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, multi-touch, hid, touchscreen

[This one was hard to choose the right SE site for. I'm picking StackOverflow as the answer is probably useless to a regular user, and interesting to a developer under a free OS.]

I've got a multitouch Acer T232hl display, and a plain-old Asus display. I first got the Acer display, then later added an additional Asus one.

Windows is correctly mapping this "Windows 8 compatible" T232hl's USB HID device (identified under Linux as "Advanced Silicon S.A CoolTouch(TM) System" device, vid:pid being 2149:2306) onto the display itself. It's not mistakenly extending the touch surface onto the Asus display, and it's not accidentally moving the surface to the Asus display.

Xorg on Ubuntu, however, by default maps the touch events across the entire surface (both displays).

- What documentation exists of the sorcery that Windows uses to correctly map the HID device's touch events to the display device? Is it a protocol or does Microsoft use the WHQL process as an opportunity to hardcode the mappings for the devices? (I do not see any custom drivers being installed.)
- Of course, if you are fully certain that this is by accident, I'll accept that answer. (If you're not certain, maybe it would serve little purpose to state what is your guess/opinion?)

Thanks!